# Not able to evaluate expression match as desired

Tags: php, regex

I need to implement a code in PHP which adds a new city (passed in `$_POST['City']`) name in database for a given `$stateID` if it does not already exist and returns its CityID generated, else use the CityID passed in `$_POST['City']`. Here is the code:

```
$stateID = substr(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'State'), 0, 2);
$city = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'City', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$cityID = NULL;
if(!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $city)){
  $cityID = $city;
  echo 'City Exists';
}
else{
  # If a new city name is entered, store it in database
  $params = array('ss', $stateID, $city);
  $cityID = $dbh->ExecuteScalar("CALL AddNewCity(?, ?, @outCityID)", $params);
  echo 'New City Added';
}
```

Problem is, whether the value of `$city` is like ***ABC*** or like ***123***, the code echoes **City Exists**.

Please ignore the code `$dbh->ExecuteScalar........`. It is using my custom built database handling library.

What is wrong with the regular expression statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex [`[a-zA-Z]`](https://regex101.com/r/5KWuN6/1) matches a lower or uppercase character and [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

You use [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) with `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`.

If you enter `ABC`, the value of `$city` will be false and `preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", false)` will return 0. The if statement will check for `if (!0)` which will be true and you will see `City Exists`

If you enter `123` the value of `$city` will be `123` and `preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", 123)` will return 0. The if statement will check for `if (!0)` which will be true and you will see `City Exists`

Comment:  I was dumb enough to see that. Thanks.